# Need to delete a specific word from a specific line in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

My textfile is like this:

"A rainbow has seven colors.

A rainbow rises just after the rainfall."

I want the word "rainbow" to be deleted from the 1st line but not from the second line and in the new file all the lines to be printed as it is without the rainbow in the first line. With a code like this:

```
infile = "old.txt"
outfile = "new.txt"

delete_word = ["rainbow"]
fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w+")
for line in fin:
      for word in delete_word:
            if 'has' in line:
                line = line.replace(word, "")
                fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

I am getting only the first line printed without 'rainbow'.

Comment: I've voted to close as a typo (extra tab before  `write`). Or do I missed something more complex hidden behind this ?

Comment: That was the full code and there was extra space. You were right for the negative voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
infile = "old.txt"
outfile = "new.txt"

delete_word = ["rainbow"]
lines = [1] #List of lines you want to delete the word from
fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w+")
line_count = 0
for line in fin:
      line_count += 1
      for word in line.split():
            if word in delete_word and line_count in lines:
                line = line.replace(word, "")
      fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to do it with line number, too?

Comment: @phoenix If it did, mark one of the answers as solved :)

Comment: Well, I tested it again. Weird, it does not work for every line. I was trying to find the reason. I think the following one is right (here "i" denotes the line number):

    f1 = open('old.txt', 'r')
    f2 = open('new.txt', 'w')
    for i, line in enumerate(f1, 1):
        if i == 1:
         line = line.replace("word_to_replace", "")
        f2.writelines(line)
    f1.close()
    f2.close()

Comment: @phoenix You didnt say what didn't work but I tested and one problem I had was that if I put rainbow in the end, split actually splits `\n` with it, so it becomes `rainbow\n`. I corrected that issue and updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I realized the "end of line" problem after I posted the above comment here. Yeah, the one you edited at last works fine. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

```
infile = "old.txt"
outfile = "new.txt"

delete_word = "rainbow"
with open(infile, "r") as fin, open(outfile, "a") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        for word == delete_word:
            line = line.replace(word, "")
        fout.write(line)
```